# QGIS: no geometry in virtual layer

Tags: qgis, geometry, virtual-layer

In QGIS 3.12.2. I created a virtual layer to use for the sort-order in a print layout as described here: 
[Sort attribute table by hidden column in Print Composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284944/sort-attribute-table-by-hidden-column-in-print-composer/339276#339276)

That works, but I have a problem with the geometry. The virtual layer does not seem to have a geometry and I was not able to create one in the edit field of the virtual layer (I tried set automatically as well as defining a point-geometry and the CRS of the original layer it is created from). In the layers panel, the virtual layer shows with a point-rendering symbol, however does not show on the map. Also zooming to the layer has no effect.

I need the geometry to [insert the page-number of the atlas sheet each point apears on](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362753/qgis-attribute-table-in-print-composer-format-numbers-and-sort-according-to-sa), see: [QGIS expression to access page-number of atlas for certain features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362615/qgis-expression-to-access-page-number-of-atlas-for-certain-features/362622#362622)

Here is what I tried, based on the first link above:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the `geometry` column from the source layer

```
select name, pop_tot, pop_ordering, geometry
from towns
where pop_tot<12000
order by pop_ordering
```

Comment: OK, that works, now the geometry appears. However, the selection does not seem to work as it should, at least not if I add an attribute tabel to the print composer. When I set the virtual layer as source, all attributes from the original layer (not only the selected ones) appear and the sort-order defined in the virtual layer is completely ignored.